# glm.fit: algorithm did not converge

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

I am working on classification using Sonar data.

I tried to perform logistic regression using the **caret** package:

```
library(mlbench)
library(caret)

data("Sonar")
head(Sonar)

#remove observations with correlation higher than 0.9
cormat <- cor(Sonar[,-61])
highlycorrelated <- findCorrelation(cormat, cutoff = 0.9)
print(highlycorrelated)
Sonar <- Sonar[-c(15,18,20),]


#Logistic Regression using caret
mod <- train(Sonar[,-61],Sonar[,61], method = "glm", preProcess = c("center", "scale"), tuneLength = 3)
mod
```

The following warning messages appear:

```
glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

Can you explain what does this message mean and what's a way to solve the problem that causes it?

Comment: Have you plotted your data to verify it looks anything like fittable?

Comment: The dataframe is composed of 60 variables. Unless I do a PCA i cannot see any graphic representation of the data itself. I am not even sure if looking at the plot of the first principal components would be something useful.